# Control when openlayers tile layers are refreshed

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms

I am displaying wms tile layers using Openlayers 6. With this version, the tile layers seem to be  refreshing when the map is starting to move (the event movestart of the map element). However, I would like the layers to be refreshing when the move is ended (event moveend).
So is there a way to change the default listeners of the map?
Thanks!
Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom load function to delay the tiles loading if the view is interacting

```
  tileLoadFunction: function(tile, src){
    if (map.getView().getInteracting()) {
      map.once('moveend', function(){
        tile.getImage().src = src;
      });
    } else {
      tile.getImage().src = src;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is great! I wasn't aware of the function tileLoadFunction nor that it was possible to change it via setTileLoadFunction. 
Thank you, it works like a charm!